# Java get word from string based off of template

Tags: java

I want to able to achieve the following

```
String template = "My name is {name}!";
String nameGet = "My name is john!";

System.out.printIn(GetWordFromTemplate(template, nameGet, "name")); //Should print john.
```

But I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Your method has the name of the template, `"name"`. So you simply do a search&replace of `"{name}"` with `nameGet`. Did you do any research? Search for *"java search and replace string"* or similar. Downvoted because no research/attempt, please see [ask], thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some brainstorming I came up with this but it does not work with more then 1 place holder

```
public String GetWordFromTemplate(String template, String input, String placeholder)
{
    if(!template.contains(placeholder)){return "";}
    String temp = input.substring(template.indexOf(placeholder));
    return temp.substring(0, temp.length() - template.substring(template.indexOf(placeholder) + placeholder.length()).length());
)
```